# Get 500 error when create response in web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my WEB API, I got 500 error.

> error status 'internal server error'. error code 500

```
public class VendorManagementController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IVendorRespository _vendorRespository;

    public VendorManagementController()
    {
        _vendorRespository = new VendorRespository();
    }

    [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public dynamic GetVendorById(int pkey)
    {
        Vendor vendor = _vendorRespository.GetVendor(pkey);
        return vendor;
    }

    // GET 
    [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public dynamic GetVendors(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var vendors = _vendorRespository.GetAllVendors();
        var pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        var pageSize = rows;
        var totalRecords = vendors.Count();
        var totalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling((float) totalRecords/(float) pageSize);
        vendors = vendors.Skip(pageIndex*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        return new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (from vendor in vendors
                select new
                {
                    cell = new string[]
                    {
                        vendor.pkey.ToString(),
                        vendor.Company,
                        vendor.ContactName,
                        vendor.ContactPhone,
                        vendor.UserName,
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(vendor.UserKey),
                        vendor.Active.ToString(),
                        vendor.FacilityId.ToString(),
                        vendor.ClientID.ToString(),
                        vendor.PhotoURL,
                        vendor.PushToGP.ToString()
                    }
                }).ToArray()
        };
    }

    // POST
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostVendor(Vendor item)
    {
        var password = CreatePassword(25);
        item.UserKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        _vendorRespository.AddVendor(item);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Vendor>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);
        string uri = Url.Link("/VendorManagement/GetVendorById", new {id = item.pkey});
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }

    private string CreatePassword(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }
}
```

it occurs at this line `var response = Request.CreateResponse<Vendor>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);` in POST.

The exception is "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: request".

Why? The `item` is not null.

Comment: what exception is thrown?

Comment: See my updated error status.@DanielA.White

Comment: i don't see the exception, just the resulting 500.

Comment: well, use try catch, put breakpoint in catch and check the exception. If you dont handle the errors, web api usually puts out a 500 when something unfortunate happens

Comment: @thsorens, Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: request

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969014(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @DanielA.White, I updated the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the answer by myself.I used asp.net 5. The framework is DNX 1.0. It seems not support `HttpResponseMessage` very well.